# How can I get the existing value key from a sharedPreferences file

Tags: android

How can I get  the existing value key from a `sharedPreferences` file?  I know that perhaps there is the `getString` method to do this.

But please see the following code, I have no any existing key value in my `sharedPreferences` file still But when I test and I want get a key value from the file(**While it has no any existing key value still**) using a condition, the first condition will run.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
    Button button;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my file",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String s = sharedPreferences.getString("1","1");
        if(s == "1")
        { textView.setText("I am a value");//it will run this condition and it seems that the getString() method is like the putString() method }
    else { textView.setText("I am not a value"); }
    }
```

Comment: `if(s == "1")` needs to be   `if(s .equals( "1"))`

Comment: is your key name also `1` ?

Comment: you are passing the default value as "1" (second argument in `getString()` method), then even if there isn't a value it will return "1", i.e. the default value

Comment: if you read the documentation `getString("1","1");` will return `1`. Why? because the second argument defines the `defaultValue`. i.e. if the key `1` is not set it will give a default value of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The second param in `sharedPreferences.getString("1","1")` is the default value if no key exist.

And `s == "1"` needs to be `"1".equals(s)`.

Comment: as ebnbin says, you are creating the default value with ("1", "1"), you should try ("1", "someUselessDefaultValue") instead

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from SharedPreferences, I normally do this:

```
public String getValueFromPreferences(String key, Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    return sharedPref.getString(key, "NONE");
}
```

Then you can call the method like this: - assuming you are calling this method inside your activity class;

```
String myValue = getValueFromPreferences("KEY", this); //this - context
//then do your thing after getting your value;
//this could mean checking if the value is "NONE" using the string .equals() method
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have updated the answer to clarify this; I rushed to answer this and should have explained more. Is there any argument against using a context or what is your point with the question marks and exclamation points?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that `getValueFromPreferences` refers to the implementation you gave above. In this case, all is good and I apologize :)